# Simpsons Tapped Out: Finding Maggie

Tags: android, simpsons-tapped-out

In the minigame where you have to find Maggie somewhere in Springfield, I always manage to locate her, but when I tap on her on the screen, nothing happens. A few times now I've had her in the centre of the screen, been tapping away furiously, and the timer has run out.

There doesn't appear to be a solution anywhere else on the web for this problem, even on EA's help website. Do you have to do something other than tap her? Or is this a bug in the game which isn't registering my tap properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the same problems with it. The imperative to have sound enabled also frustrating with this mini game.

At least with the tapping once you've found her, they have tap area problems, but there is a solution:

Don't tap on her directly, but tap on the center of the building where she's sitting.

There is also delay in the animation even after you've got the right tap spot, but it should usually start about 2 or 3 seconds after you've tapped the right spot.